# ScriptX Print functionality is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a requirement of printing documents and I am using ScriptX for this purpose.
Everything works fine and prints the documents in IE11.But in IE8,I am getting an error,Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

My printing code looks like this

```
function PrintFunctionality(url, title,data)
{  

  if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {

        //alert('ie browser');
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        var htmltext = '<html><head><title>' + title + '</title>';
        htmltext += "<object id='factory' style='display:none' classid='clsid:1663ed61-23eb-11d2-b92f-008048fdd814' codebase='http://localhost/smsx.cab#Version=7,5,0,20'></object>";
        htmltext += "<script src='http://localhost/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>";
        htmltext += "<script src='http://localhost/meadco-scriptx-1.0.2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
        htmltext += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        htmltext += "$(function () {";
        htmltext += "if (MeadCo.ScriptX.Init()) {MeadCo.ScriptX.PrintPage(false);}});</script>";
        htmltext += '</head><body>';
        htmltext += data;
        htmltext += '</body></html>';
        printWindow.document.write(htmltext);
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();

        return false;
    }
};
```

and the installed version of script x in my system is:

The installed version of ScriptX is: 7.5.0.20

The installed version of Security Manager is: 7.5.0.20

The installed version of Print component is: 7.5.0.20

Any thing to change in the code to work for IE8 ?

Answer (score 0):

Background - there are a number of issues:

1. the printing functionality as shown will not run because IE 8 is Trident v4
2. The code is assuming that the behaviour on document.close() is synchronous - it isn't. Neither the loading of script files nor the initialisation of ScriptX is synchronous. when printWindow.close() is called the browser is possibly still downloading stuff and/or running startup code and kills the window before it has a chance to start the print. That is works with IE11 is because everything is in the cache and it is being used on a 'fast' machine.
3. jQuery does not initialise properly in this scenario (proof: remove all references to ScriptX and script leaving simply jQuery inclusion and $(function() {}}); -- it still errors even with jQuery 1.3
4. The code is trying to print the document twice - via MeadCo.ScriptX.PrintPage() and printWindow.print().

In this scenario, jQuery and meaco-scriptx-1.0.2 offer no real benefit.

This is a temporary window that should be able to assume that ScriptX is already installed. The answer/change to make it work in any version of IE is to go old-school:

```
function PrintFunctionality(url, title, data) {
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
    var htmltext = '<html><head><title>' + title + '</title>';
    htmltext += "<object id='factory' style='display:none' classid='clsid:1663ed61-23eb-11d2-b92f-008048fdd814'></object>";
    htmltext += "<" + "script type='text/javascript'>";
    htmltext += "function printDocument() { window.setTimeout('window.close()',3000); factory.printing.print(false); }</" + "script>";
    htmltext += "</head><body onload='printDocument()'>";
    htmltext += data;
    htmltext += '</body></html>';
    printWindow.document.write(htmltext);
    printWindow.document.close();
    return false;            
}
```

Note that the window closes itself and it does after a delay that is deemed long enough for the print to have completed (spooled). It is a quirk of this scenario that you must call window.setTimeout() before calling factory.printing.print() or the timeout may not fire.